# Remove number from default name in VS item template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

When I go to "Add New Item" in VisualStudio and choose my custom item template (and also with the default item templates) the default entry for the name is `XY1.cs`, always having the `1` in the end, although the `1` is not given in the vstemplate file.

So as far as I know VS increments this number if an element with the same name already exists.

But why does it start with `1` and is not left out? And can I prevent VS from adding the `1` in my custom template? I want to add an additional string to the given name in my template but often the user does not remove the `1` or does just oversee it, so it results in `{WantedFilename}1{AdditionalString}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mark Wilson-Thomas, Senior Program Manager, Visual Studio IDE Team on [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/07/17/visual-studio-intellicode-inferring-coding-conventions-for-consistent-code/)

> Creating through the File-New Item dialog adds a “1” To the filename
>   If you use the File-New Item dialog route to create your EditorConfig,
>   in Visual Studio versions prior to 15.8 Preview 4, you’ll need to
>   manually remove the superfluous “1” Prefixing the EditorConfig file
>   name in the dialog. This is fixed in the 15.8 Preview 4 release.

**Update**

This announcement seems to only apply to `.editorconfig` files (and some others like `.manifest`)

See [How to create a VisualStudio item template that does not offer numbered file names by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856878/how-to-create-a-visualstudio-item-template-that-does-not-offer-numbered-file-nam) for more info.

Comment: Does this VS change (regarding the EditorConfig) help in case of a custom item template?

Comment: I am currently not working with VS but I suppose it does, would be weird if it only fixes it for editorconfig files. Just try it.

Comment: Apparently this is not a public feature that would be available for custom item templates. VS seems to handle some built-in templates/extensions specially. See the tests and discussions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856878/how-to-create-a-visualstudio-item-template-that-does-not-offer-numbered-file-nam

Comment: Interesting. Then I think it won't change in the near future :D