# How to create a VisualStudio item template that does not offer numbered file names by default

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, visual-studio-sdk

If I create an item template with default name `foo.txt`, Visual Studio by default offers the name `foo1.txt` in the add new dialog, even if there is no `foo.txt` in the folder.

This is normally fine, but I would need to create an item template, that does **not** offer a "1" suffix for the file name by default, exactly like the `App.config` template behaves.

I have checked the `App.vstemplate` file in the VS2019 installation, but I don't see any special setting that would cause this behavior.

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>foo.txt</DefaultName>
    <Name>Foo.txt file</Name>
    <Description>A foo.txt.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem>foo.txt</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Shows in the add new dialog as:
[image]

Comment: I've not seen that behavior before. Could you add a minimal example of an item template that repros this behavior?

Comment: I have added an example, but basically almost all of the item templates work like that, except App.config and App.manifest and maybe a few others.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Do you think it's possible that they're special casing some of the templates? app/web.config wouldn't work if folks didn't realize that integer tacked on the end would make the file useless. I don't see anything you're doing differently here that should make a difference. The docs don't look promising, either.  I'd consider opening a connect with MS about this, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, seems like it is a built-in behavior for some specific names/extensions. I will open a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I'm afraid the answer would be negative. I think this
behavior is by design and can't be controlled by any Element in the
.vstemplate.

I've reproduced this issue in my side. And one interesting thing I found is if we change the file extensions to `.manifest` and this issue goes away.

For example:

If the Item template I want to create is something like a `foo.manifest` instead of `foo.txt`, then when I add this item in new project it won't display the `1` suffix. You can easily confirm this point by change all your `foo.txt` content to `foo.manifest`.

[image]

I agree with Will that they're special casing some of the templates. And to be more specific, this behavior is special for the file extensions of the Item we created. I haven't done anything differently when creating `xxx.manifest Item`, but it just makes a difference from the `xxx.txt Item`. So I would think there is a invisible and unknown rule to control this behavior, and this behavior may not be changed or controlled in custom extension. It would be something like a rule designed by the Product Team I believe.

In my opinion, it's not supported by current VS SDK to control the behavior to let VS won't display `'1' suffix` for item whose file extension is `.txt`. And if you do want this feature, go [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) to share your great idea there. Actually after your reminder, it would be better if this feature comes then we can **really** control the `Default Name`, so if you decide to post your idea, share the link in your question and members interested in it would help vote for it.

Hope it helps and if i misunderstand anything,  feel free to let me know:)

Comment: Thx. It is clear and this is what my suspicion was. In my case this is important, because I would like to use the template for adding a config file for a tool (SpecFlow) that expects a specific config file name by convention (specflow.json). I will post a request for the dev community and link it here.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help:)